# What is the DeviceInfo folder in my home folder

Tags: macos

Since a few days there is a DeviceInfo folder in my home folder. In it, there is a text file. What is this and where does it come from?

I can delete the folder, but it will reappear after a few days!

Comment: What's in the text file?

Comment: a string with probably a device id

Comment: In a Terminal I'd run the following command in an attempt to see if that text string is a Device ID, `system_profiler | grep '$string'`, replace "$string" with what's in the text file.  If it outputs something then investigate further with directing output of `system_profiler` to a text file where it can be searched from TextEdit to see the information around that string.  `system_profiler > filename.txt`

Comment: it doesn't output anything

Comment: you may need `system_profiler -detailLevel full` to see everything.

Comment: Could you please explain, what I should do?

Comment: What is the output of `lsof ~/DeviceInfo/<text file>`? If the command has no ouput, delete the folder and run `while :; do lsof +D ~/DeviceInfo 2>/dev/null; sleep 1; done` until the folder is created and post the output (if any).

Comment: there wasn't any output at all.